# Child to Parent setState is one step behind

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a basic calculator type app and I've encountered a problem. I'm passing state from child to parent and it seems to always be one step behind.

I've tried setting condition in the `onChange` function to set state once the length is 3 but even the length is behind. I've done a lot of research and have learned that setState is asynchronous but I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

[image]

**Parent.js**

```
DL = getDLScore => {
  this.setState({ dlScore: getDLScore }, () =>
    console.log('state', this.state.dlScore)
  );
};

<Text>
  Points - {this.state.dlScore} + {this.state.ptScore}
</Text>

<View>
  <Deadlift mosLevel={this.state.mosLevel} handler={this.DL} />
</View>
```

**Child.js**

```
getDLScore(e) {
    let i;
    let deadliftScore = this.state.deadliftScore;

    i = deadliftScore.scoreSheet[e];

    if (e != '') {
      if (this.props.mosLevel === '1') {
        if (e < 180) {
          return <Text style={styles.failed}>fail</Text>;
        } else if (e >= 340) {
          return 100;
        } else {
          return i;
        }


handleInputChange = () => {
  this.props.handler(this.getDLScore(this.state.dlScoreInput));
};

<View>
  <TextInput
    onChangeText={dlScoreInput => this.setState({ dlScoreInput })}
    style={styles.input}
    keyboardType="number-pad"
    autoCorrect={false}
    maxLength={3}
    value={this.state.dlScoreInput}
    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
  />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should in the child component pass the state to the parent by just calling

`this.props.handler(this.state.dlScoreInput)`
so your onchange method should look as follows

```
handleInputChange = () => {
 this.props.handler(this.state.dlScoreInput);
};
```

Comment: this.getDLScore is a function for calculating the score based on dlScoreInput's state so it's required. This change still made everything one step behind.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by one step behind?

Comment: See the two pictures in my original post. When I enter 340, the points to the right show 100 but the points on top shows fail. When I delete the 0 from 340, the points to the right shows fail and the points on top shows 100.

The points to the right should match the points on top.

Comment: Ok I get it now can you show how you compute the value on top and the ones on the right?. My best guess is the logic that has some issues.

Comment: Added the logic to get the values on the right. The values on top is the same as on the right, just being passed from child to parent.